# Android change AppCompat theme and colors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

in my project i'm using `AppCompat` for my application work in all version of android but this theme of that by default is not good for my application and i want to change that.

my manifest is :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

and i dont want to change that. in this below screen shot of application how to change `CYAN` color in bottom of `ActionBarTab` and `ListView` selected items?

[image]

or can change parent theme for all changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)

Answer (score 1):

### ***Have a look at these links :-***

1. [Styling Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)
2. [Customizing overall app style](https://gist.github.com/ricardoalcocer/8152522)
3. [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)